# Navigation Slug Issue (Structure Section)

Tags: structure, navigation

I am trying to setup a navigation on a site. I am using a Structure Section called "pages", however, when I changed the "Top-Level Entries" to just `{slug}` and the nested levels to `{parent.uri}/{slug}`, I am getting URLs like `about/profile-1` and `about/biography-1`.

I am guessing the reason why I am getting `-1` is due to the fact that the entry already exists in my About channel.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If the navigation section is strictly for structuring your navigation I would disable 'Entries in this section have their own URLs' and add a entries relation field to connect your content with the navigation items.

A standalone plugin could also help you out: https://github.com/am-impact/amnav